# Mongoose is not saving array in the mongo db

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

tasks array is not getting saving the data base when I'm sending data from postman.

I'm sending data by hitting postman but it is only saying the title field values but not tasks array values like below

{
"title": "my first test59",
"tasks": ["task1","task2","task3"]
}

Since I'm using create method save is not needed that's why I'm not using it in my model. I'm not getting it why it is not working out.

My model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const toDoSchema = new schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        require: [true, "title is required"],
        trim: true
        },
    tasks:{
        type:[String],
        trim: true
        }
    });
const toDoModel = mongoose.model("toDo", toDoSchema);
module.exports = toDoModel;



//importing model
const toDoModel = require('../models/ToDoModel');

//creating controller function
const createToDoController = async (req,res)=>{
    try{
    const {title,toDoTasks} = req.body;

    if(!title) //input validation
    { 
        throw new Error("Please provide the title");
    }
    const newToDo = await toDoModel.create({ title, toDoTasks });
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: "User Created Successfully",
        newToDo,
      });
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Unable to perform create operation",
            error: err
        })
        res.send(err.message);
    } 

}
module.exports = createToDoController;
```

controller.js

```
//importing model
const toDoModel = require('../models/ToDoModel');

//creating controller function
const createToDoController = async (req,res)=>{
    try{
    const {title,toDoTasks} = req.body;

    if(!title) //input validation
    { 
        throw new Error("Please provide the title");
    }
    const newToDo = await toDoModel.create({ title, toDoTasks });
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: "User Created Successfully",
        newToDo,
      });
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Unable to perform create operation",
            error: err
        })
        res.send(err.message);
    } 

}
module.exports = createToDoController;
```

[image]

Comment: Your post body has no property "toDoTasks" you try to access in the controller functions. Every where you write "tasks" but never access these anywhere. You just defined that in your schema but never sets them anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Change "tasks" instead of "toDoTasks" in request body. It will work.

```
const {title,tasks} = req.body;
```